# How to keep search icon for the input text field with out overlapping the text and icon in ie8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am struggling with a small issue, the issue itself looks simple but it is eating my time.
I have a search input field with search icon on the left side. I have given the search icon as a background image and placed the icon on left side design wise it looks perfect but the issue is when I enter the long text in the text field it is overlapping with the search icon.I have given the padding let to the text field it is some what working fine in modern browsers like Chrome, mozilla and IE10 but in IE8 it is giving the same issue. Please check the below code what I have written.

```css
.search-box {
line-height: 17px;
width: 250px;
background: url(../images/sprite-img-repeat.png) 0 -25px no-repeat #fff;
margin-right: 8px;
padding: 3px 0px 3px 25px;
border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
color: #545454;
}
```

```html
<input name="search" type="text" id="searchTextBox" class="-search-box ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
```

And I am giving one more information it has the auto complete suggestion functionality for the input.
I can not able to add the screenshot here it is giving you need at least 10 reputation to post images.
Any suggestion on how to get this work on IE8.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you are to post the whole code regarding the search bar because this way it is not easy to understand how you have created the structure but from what I understand it looks like that you are giving the search input field the icon background, am I right.

If this is the case then you would have to change the structure to use in ie8.

```
<div class="search-box">
  <div class="icon">icon</div>
  <input name="search" type="text" id="searchTextBox" class="-search-box ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

The icon should not be an background img in the search field, it should be separate, you can use text img replacement for it.

CSS

```
.search-box {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.icon{
  text-indent:-9999px;
  float:left;
  background: url(../images/sprite-img-repeat.png) 0 -25px no-repeat #fff;
  width: "width of icon"
  height: "height of icon"
}
.search-box {
line-height: 17px;
width: 250px;
margin-right: 8px;
padding: 3px 0px 3px 25px;
border: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
color: #545454;
float:right or left
}
```